# What is wrong with :s##// in vimrc?

Tags: vim

I just want a convenient note function:

```
map <silent> <nowait> <M-n> ^:call Note()<CR>

func! Note()
  if &filetype == 'cpp'
    if getline(".")[col(".") - 1] == '/'
      execute 'normal! xx'
    else
      execute 's##//'
    endif
  elseif &filetype == 'vim'
    if getline(".")[col(".") - 1] == '"'
      silent :s#^"#
    else
      silent :s#^#"
    endif
  endif
endfunc
```

Vim said:

> E488： Trailing characters

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Commenting is a very common and [many plugins](https://vimawesome.com/?q=comment) are already available. I use [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary)

Answer (score 0):

Lets expand this a bit for clarity:

```
:s##//#
```

An empty pattern in a substitution means to use the last used pattern, `"/`. If that pattern does not exist then you get an `E488` error. I think it is more likely that you wanted your pattern to be `^` or `.`

Some more thoughts:

- As a general rule it is best to supply a mode when making mappings
- Use `*noremap` variants if able
- For maintainability it can be helpful to use full names instead of shortened commands. e.g. `function` vs `func`
- This handles comments for 2 languages, so it becomes brittle to expand
- Consider using `'commentstring'`
- Should probably thing about a visual mappings and/or creating an operator
- `:s` will set the last used search pattern which could be surprising if the search pattern is not restored

Commenting is a common pattern yet surprisingly tricky to get right. Best to stand the [shoulders of giants](https://vimawesome.com/?q=comment) and use a plugin. If you want a quick-and-dirty commenting script you can use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/13bde011c01b7fc188c5) as a jumping off point

Comment: Thanks, i change it to :s#^#//# but still get an E488.

Comment: and actually the "nomal! xx" also return E488

Comment: I try the plug you recomment，and it is very useful.  And thank you for helping me, it's my first time to use stackoverflow. I use to think study is lonely and helpless but now i feel good with your help.